# CakePHP items per page helper

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

How generate from pagination helper a drop-down list with items per page? Default value is 20 items per page, I want to get something like this:

```
Show 
<select>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
</select> 
entries
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HkWuH/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @BigToach mentioned I have add this to method in my controller

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'paramType' => 'querystring',
    'limit' => 30,
    'maxLimit' => 100
);
```

and add following code to my View

```
$limit = $this->params->query['limit'];
$options = array( 5 => '5', 10 => '10', 20 => '20' );

echo $this->Form->create(array('type'=>'get'));

echo $this->Form->select('limit', $options, array(
    'value'=>$limit, 
    'default'=>20, 
    'empty' => FALSE, 
    'onChange'=>'this.form.submit();', 
    'name'=>'limit'
    )
);
echo $this->Form->end();
```

Answer (score 2):

The results per page is driven by the 'limit' parameter in the paginate array

```
<?php
$this->paginate = array(
    'paramType' => 'querystring',
    'limit' => 30,
);
?>
```

You can override this by setting limit as a query string value. Ex:

```
?limit=40
```

From there you just need to build a drop down that changes the URL when they select the number per page.

You might also want to implement [maxLimit](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#limit-the-maximum-number-of-rows-that-can-be-fetched%20maxLimit) so users don't change this value to an extremely large number.

Answer (score 2):

(*This is really just a comment on [Warthel4578](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2393509/warthel4578)'s answer, but I don't have enough rep to comment yet... just wanted to share this tip for anyone who runs into the same issue I had with this solution*)

So I kept getting the error "Undefined index: limit" (on the line that sets `$limit = $this->params->query['limit'];`) upon initial page load of my paginated results, although after changing the dropdown value and the paginated results refreshing, the error went away.

In place of `$limit = $this->params->query['limit'];`, I had to use this in my View:

```
$page_params = $this->Paginator->params();
$limit = $page_params['limit'];
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you could use :

```
// Use the defaults.

echo $this->Paginator->limitControl();
```

More information at

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/paginator.html#creating-a-limit-selectbox-control